# insert a block to xml file java

Tags: java, xml, string, automation

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DbVisualizer>
 <Databases>
    <Database id="1">
      <Alias>MyMssqlServer</Alias>
      <Url />
      <Driver>SQL Server (jTDS)</Driver>
      <Userid>db_monitor</Userid>
      <Profile>auto</Profile>
      <Type>sqlserver</Type>
      <Password>ABCDEFGHSIFJSDSDKJSD</Password>
      <ServerInfoFormat>1</ServerInfoFormat>
      <AutoDetectType>true</AutoDetectType>
      <Properties>
        <Property key="dbvis.ConnectionModeMigrated">true</Property>
      </Properties>
      <UrlFormat>0</UrlFormat>
      <UrlVariables>
        <Driver>
          SQL Server (jTDS)
          <UrlVariable UrlVariableName="Server">192.168.1.1</UrlVariable>
          <UrlVariable UrlVariableName="Port">1433</UrlVariable>
          <UrlVariable UrlVariableName="Database">abcdefg</UrlVariable>
        </Driver>
      </UrlVariables>
      <SshSettings>
        <SshEnabled>false</SshEnabled>
        <SshHost />
        <SshPort>22</SshPort>
        <SshUserid />
        <SshPassword />
        <SshPrivateKeyFile />
        <SshPassphrase />
      </SshSettings>
    </Database>
</DbVisualizer>
```

And I have a provision process that generated new server for me with sqlserver on it and I need to add there properties to this XML file, so basically I need to duplicate the section of the element "Database" change a few properties and push it right after the Database element that already exist,
For that I created a template for this section in an external file I am changing what ever I need but how can append the entire section to the file, I am aware that I can do it one element at a time but thats a lot of element so I want to push this entire section after the one I have:

```html
<Database id="IDNUMBER">
      <Alias>MACHINAME</Alias>
      <Url />
      <Driver>SQL Server (jTDS)</Driver>
      <Userid>db_monitor</Userid>
      <Profile>auto</Profile>
      <Type>sqlserver</Type>
      <Password>ABCDEFGHSIFJSDSDKJSD==</Password>
      <ServerInfoFormat>1</ServerInfoFormat>
      <AutoDetectType>true</AutoDetectType>
      <Properties>
        <Property key="dbvis.ConnectionModeMigrated">true</Property>
      </Properties>
      <UrlFormat>0</UrlFormat>
      <UrlVariables>
        <Driver>
          SQL Server (jTDS)
          <UrlVariable UrlVariableName="Server">MACHINEIP</UrlVariable>
          <UrlVariable UrlVariableName="Port">1433</UrlVariable>
          <UrlVariable UrlVariableName="Database">abcdefg</UrlVariable>
        </Driver>
      </UrlVariables>
      <SshSettings>
        <SshEnabled>false</SshEnabled>
        <SshHost />
        <SshPort>22</SshPort>
        <SshUserid />
        <SshPassword />
        <SshPrivateKeyFile />
        <SshPassphrase />
      </SshSettings>
    </Database>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have the main xml document inside the object `myDocument` which is an instance of the class `org.w3c.dom.Document` and you have your current template instance inside the object `newDatabase` which is an instance of the class `org.w3c.dom.Node`.

Now you have to retrieve the `<Databases />` node from `myDocument` and append the `newDataBase` node to it

```
NodeList nodes = myDocument.getElementsByTagName("Databases");
nodes.item(0).appendChild(newDataBase);
```

The appendChild() method adds a node after the last child node of the specified element node.

-- EDIT: to read your template from file and obtain the node you can do

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH);
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(fileInputStream);
Node newDataBase = document.getDocumentElement();
```

-- SECOND EDIT: before appending the `newDataBase` node to `myDocument` you must duplicate 
   the node and transfer ownership of the node into the destination document with this 
   line of code:

```
   Node newNode = myDocument.importNode(newDataBase, true);
```

then you can append `newNode` to `myDocument` using the previous code.

Comment: for now the section on the new database element is inside a temp txt file , how do I import this content of the txt file to anode object?

Comment: The node needs to be imported, +1